# Play doesn't recognize changes to .scala.html files

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am currently working on a Play Framework project. I already deployed the application to a server, but now I want to make some changes to some of the views.

If I make changes in one of the views, for example, change some text, it doesn't show in the browser. The play console also doesn't show the message that it's compiling a source because I changed it.

If I make changes to some Java Code, for example, I add a `System.out.println()` to one of the controllers, Play immediately notices that. Also, the console shows the message as it should:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /Users/stefanroth/Desktop/Neuer Ordner/Peri/IDP_Benchmarking-master/target/scala-2.11/classes...
```

I already tried to run the compile command in the Play console, but that didn't do anything. This is driving me crazy, since I know I make changes, but they aren't taking affect, and there is no obvious reason for it.

If it helps, I work with the IntelliJ IDE.

So, what is causing that? And how can this be fixed?

EDIT:

#### `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.heroku" % "sbt-heroku" % "2.0.0")
```

#### `build.sbt`:

```
name := """IDP_Benchmarking_3"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala, PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    cache,
    javaWs
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.4.0-1",
    "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.6",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.10-FINAL",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9",
    "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.6",
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41"
)

unmanagedBase := {
    if (sys.props("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("mac"))
        baseDirectory.value / "lib/OSX_Linux"
    else if (sys.props("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win"))
        baseDirectory.value / "lib/WIN"
    else
        baseDirectory.value / "lib"
}

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

herokuAppName in Compile := "benchmarkingsoccerclubs"
```

EDIT 2:

I just noticed that the same problem occurs when I make changes to a javascript file.

Comment: if you stop play and compile it manually + run again, the changes will show?

Comment: You can change [sbt log level](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Logging.html#Change+the+logging+level+globally) to better debug what is happening. Change it to `debug` and see if you can get more information about the watch process. Besides that, it would be good to see your `build.sbt` file and `project/plugins.sbt`.

Comment: @pedrorijo91 What do you mean with compiling it manually?

Comment: Where are the JavaScript files? Also, are the files name using `Scala.html` (with a capital `S`) or `scala.html` (with lower case `s`)? Were you able to change the log level for sbt?